# Xcode 6.0.1 CTRL-Drag from view to source code not working

Tags: xcode

I'm following a tutorial and when I CTRL-drag from the view to the source code in Xcode nothing happens. I get the blue line but when I drop it in the source code I don't get the menu where I can choose options. Please see screenshots:
[image: Project]

When I CTRL-drag the label DSA from the view to the source file on the right side of the editor and drop right after @interface nothing happens.
I'm using latest XCode 6.0.1.

I'm supposed to get a menu like the screenshot below (grabbed from the tutorial book)

[image: Expected Results]

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. Had to associate a class to xib file as per screenshot below:
[image: Solution]

Answer (score -1):

your xib file doesn't know its class, try doing this in main.storyboard.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. However I'm not using a storyboard.